# Square root of strictly convex function is not convex

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

I am trying to prove that if $f : \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R_+}$ is a strictly convex function then $g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}$ will not be necessarily convex.

I have started with using the definition that $f(x)$ is strictly convex, so it must hold that

$f(\theta x+ (1-\theta)y) < \theta f(x) + (1-\theta)f(y) \qquad$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $\theta \in (0,1)$

Then since $f : \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R_+}$, I proceed with

$\sqrt{f(\theta x+ (1-\theta)y)} < \sqrt{\theta f(x) + (1-\theta)f(y)} \qquad$

$\sqrt{f(\theta x+ (1-\theta)y)} < \sqrt{\theta f(x)} + \sqrt{(1-\theta)f(y)} \qquad$

$\ \ \ \ {g(\theta x+ (1-\theta)y)} < \sqrt{\theta} g(x) + \sqrt{(1-\theta)}g(y) \qquad$

But this does not prove anything..

I have figured out that what happens is that g(x) can be concave, but I cannot figure out how to reverse the inequality to show that..

Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying something this complicated? The structure of  the statement you're considering means that you just need a single counterexample, of which $|x|^{1.1}$ is one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have already found counterexamples but I thought it must be simple to show it and that I was just confused. Isn't it simple?

Comment: To prove a statement of the form (if $A$ is true then $B$ is not necessarily true), all you need is one counterexample where $A$ is true and $B$ is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really expect to write a "proof" that something fails sometimes.

In this case, since $x^r$ is strictly convex when $r>1$ and not convex when $r<1$, you can take $g(x)=|x|^{3/2}$, and then $\sqrt{g(x)}=|x|^{3/4}$ is not convex.

Comment: I understand, I was expecting to end up with some possible cases while solving the inequality, but this is not the case. Thanks!

Comment: In your opinion, can I provide a visual proof?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "visual proof".

Comment: I mean plot the two functions (and f(x)=x for comparison) to show that one is convex and the other concave without solving the algebraic inequalities.